# What is the alternative for cl /NODEFAULTLIB in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, cl

I have done a c++ project that doesn't depend on any c/c++ runtime but only windows api
I can build it easily with msvc by passing -NODEFAULTLIB to the linker and I end up with a small executable that doesn't depend on any c/c++ runtime
I'm thinking now to publish my project and people will be able to build it without msvc (it requires huge disk space)
So I decided to go with mingw-w64 and my project will be built also on linux with mingw
But I don't want the runtime library to be linked to my application so how can I disable linking to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-z nodefaultlib` seems to do it, see:

http://rextester.com/SAL68483

Reference:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options

Comment: I get undefined reference to `__main' . in msvc I usually set it with /entry:main but for gcc I tried -e main but didn't solve it

Comment: Hmmm.  Can you post the full error message back to your question please?  Thanks.